# Javascript Pic Slideshow Failing?

Tags: javascript, slideshow, setinterval

FOr some reason my code is not executing properly. i am trying to program a slideshow with javascript. Im using a for loop to pull and populate the src files from a created array and change the pic every 3 seconds. THe page loads and the first pic is present but when the interval occurs the first pic dissapears and nothing falls in its place. What am I doing wrong?

```
<img name="mainSlide" id="mainSlide" src="images/mainPagePhotos/facebook-20131027-180258.png" alt="">

var mainSlidePics = ("facebook-20131027-180258.png","IMG_9694116683469.jpg","IMG_28452769990897.jpg");
window.onload = setInterval("mainSlide();", 3000);
function mainSlide() {
    for(i=0; i<mainSlidePics.length; i++ ) {
        document.images.mainSlide.src = "images/mainPagePhotos/" + mainSlidePics[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried getting the Id first?

```
var mainSlide = document.getElementById("mainSlide");

mainSlide.src = "images/mainPagePhotos/" + mainSlidePics[i];
```

also a forloop is a loop that finishes its loops even in one call.
try

```
var i = 0;
window.onload = setInterval("mainSlide(i);", 3000);
mainSlide(int j){
      mainSlide.src = "images/mainPagePhotos/" + mainSlidePics[i];
      setInterval("mainSlide(j++);", 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to correctly declare the array.
Then you have to move the counter variable outside the function triggered by setInterval.
Then pass the reference of the function to setInterval.

```
<img name="mainSlide" id="mainSlide" src="images/mainPagePhotos/facebook-20131027-180258.png" alt="">

<script type="text/javascript">
var mainSlidePics = ["facebook-20131027-180258.png","IMG_9694116683469.jpg","IMG_28452769990897.jpg"];
var position = 0;
function changePic() {
     position = (position+1) % mainSlidePics.length;
     document.images.mainSlide.src = "images/mainPagePhotos/" + mainSlidePics[position];

}
window.onload = function() {
  setInterval(changePic, 3000);
};
</script>
```